# Get domain of a POST request

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a script that makes a ***POST*** request to my website from other websites (different domains) and I need to know if it's possible to get what's that other domain.

Like: **helloworld.com** uses my script and it executes a ***POST*** request with **mywebsite.com**. How does **mywebsite.com** know that the request is from **helloworld.com**?

I have tried with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` but that's not working.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` maybe?

Comment: What does `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` return? Have you enabled this setting? For example in Apache you'll need `HostnameLookups On` inside httpd.conf.

Comment: You should include a key so you know who's doing the request.

Comment: be more precise, what sort of script do you have ? JavaScript ? if so maybe just change a script to add an additional parameter to the request with a domain in which it was executed.

Comment: The script will be open-source, so I can't include a key.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` gives me a blank response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inspect the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

In PHP this would be `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`.

In JavaScript, this would be `document.referrer`.

Note that it can be inaccurate and is easy to be spoofed, so it's value should be taken with a pinch of salt.

---

To provide a little bit more detail on how you *can* do this reliably (albeit with the cooperation of the remote server):

1. Let `secret` be a arbitrary string (`abc123`).
2. Let `key` be a random string which is unique to each request (e.g. the current time)
3. Generate `token` by `md5(secret + key)`.
4. Have the remote server include `key` and `token` (but **not** `secret`) in the POST request.
5. On your server, ensure that `md5(secret + key) === token`

Because no-one  knows the secret, you can guarantee that the request originated from the remote server. Of course, it's *then* possible for someone to request the form from the remote server, steal the `key` and `token`, and then forward the request to yourself...

Comment: Is there some reliable way to get it?

Comment: No. The only way to do this would be to have `helloworld.com` generate tokens with a secret, pass the token in the request, and have `mywebsite.com` verify the validity of the token using the same secret.

Comment: @RyanCasas: I've added how to do that to my answer, in case it interests you.

Comment: Yeah, really interesting! Thank you :D

Comment: @Matt +1 but use sha1 which is more secure

Answer (score 1):

You should use `HTTP_REFERER`. But it can not be trusted fully

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Take a look here, where it is documented: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']
```

To get the page from which the request is made

Answer (score 1):

You could save the ip. `gethostbyaddr($ip)`
If the script is executed automatically, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` won't work.

Comment: Because this value is set by the user's browser. If the server runs it by itself, there is no browser.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I read the question differently; I thought he meant `helloworld.com` hosted a `<form>` whose `target` was set to `mywebsite.com`; in which case the `HTTP_REFERER` should work fine.

Comment: Yes in case a user submits it, the referer should be fine.

Comment: Hm, the script is executed once the user chooses one option, and it's requested via jQuery's `$.post` to my server. Would it work?